# Scroll Horizontal in C# Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, scroll

I recently moved from java to c# and trying to scroll a webpage horizontally using javascript, but it is not working.

Also tried using actions class, this is also not working

Below is the code i tried

IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;

js.ExecuteScript("window.scrollBy(500,0)");

Could anyone help in resolving this.

Comment: You can use jquery function `scrollLeft()` if you application supports jquery..:)

Answer (score 0):

Try `js.ExecuteScript("scroll(500,0)");` It would work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are better off scrolling to a particular element.

Here is the c# code that I use for scrolling...

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("identifier")) as IWrapsElement;
var locatableElement = element.WrappedElement as ILocatable;
var pos = locatableElement.LocationOnScreenOnceScrolledIntoView;
```

Or you may use the javascript like below

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("identifier"));
var script = "arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);";
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript(script, element);
```