# How to scroll right in Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
    public void ScrollRight()
    {
        Sleep(100);
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        Sleep(100);
        action.SendKeys(Keys.Right).Build().Perform();
    }
```

I have just typed this function in order to scroll. This function could not be worked in vs code. How can I scroll right or left?

Comment: CAn't you just use this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/12293212/1663001

Comment: _"This function could not be worked in vs code"_ - Do you mean it works elsewhere, but there's just an issue running it via VS Code?

Comment: I think your answers can be found on older threads: [42507826](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42507826/how-to-do-horizontal-scroll-using-selenium-webdriver), and [39241231](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39241231/scroll-horizontal-in-c-sharp-selenium)